# What module is $\Bbb{C}[x,y](n)_{(x)}$? Serres twisting sheaf $\mathcal{O}(n)|_{D_+(x)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I am reading Hartshorne's textbook on algebraic geometry.

I have just read the definition of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on $\text{Proj}(S)$ for a graded ring $S$. I want to first understand $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on $\Bbb P^1$, where $S=\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ with the standard grading.

Then by Proposition 5.11, we know that $\mathcal{O}(n)|_{D_+(x)}\cong \Bbb{C}[x,y](n)_{(x)}$ is the degree $0$ terms in the localised ring, after shifting the grading by $n$. I originally thought that we shift the grading by $n$, in which case $x^n,y^n$ have degree $0$ in $\Bbb{C}[x,y](n)$, and thus $x$ has degree $1-n$, and in the localisation, $1/x$ has degree $1-n-2$?

In the proof though it says that $S(n)_f$ has the degree $n$ elements of $S_f$, so it seems they localise with the **old** degree of $f$, back in $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ rather than the degree in $\Bbb{C}[x,y](n)$.

Well what module **is** $\Bbb{C}[x,y](n)_{(x)}$ after all? I.e. what is $\mathcal{O}(n)|_{U_0}$ the $\widetilde{globalisation}$ of?

I guess it's the $\Bbb{C}[y/x]$-module spanned by $x^{-i}y^{n+i}$ for $i\geq -n$?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_of_projective_spaces#Classification_of_vector_bundles) : the quotients of homogeneous polynomials $\in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ of degree $n+m,m$ with the denominator $\not \in x \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ (otherwise the denominator not in any maximal ideal above $(x)$) ?

Comment: I'm just trying to work straight from the definition in Hartshorne @reuns 

Also I think denominator not in $x\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ should be $\mathcal{O}(n)|_{D_+(y)}$?

Comment: You have an issue here: you are treating the $x$ that you localize at as an element of the module instead of an element of the ring. This is what's causing you trouble - the degree of $f$ in the _ring_ isn't changed by shifting the grading on the _module_.